# CSS transition not working at drop down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

I am using the code of this page:

> https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch

Now, my CSS looks like:

```
.subs {
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(-2em);
z-index: -1;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;

width: auto;
float: left;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
border: 2px solid #66ec95;
background: #f4f7f5;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: -10px;
}

/* SELECTORS */

#nav li:hover > .subs { /* with this seletor, only the last property is working */
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
transform: translateY(0%);
transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
margin-top: 10px; /* just for test, only this is working */
}

#nav li :hover + .subs { /* this time, the animation are working but other problems occured (see above) */
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
transform: translateY(0%);
transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li aria-haspopup="true">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a>
                <div class="subs" id="service-subs" aria-haspopup="false">
                    <a href="~/services/all">Product List</a><br />
                    <a href="~/services/projects">Projects</a><br />
                </div>
            </li>
            ... and so on
```

So, the second selector for `.subs` displays the animation but it breaks when I move my cursor into `.subs` and it's also interrupted many times on displaying because of cursor detects `.subs` while showing the menu.

Furthermore, I can't understand why does it work with sibling selector when `.subs` is a child of `#nav li`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problems with the link you provided. Can you explain what is the problem there?

Comment: Expecially, when I use the second selector and move the mouse to a menu item in the nav bar, the submenu will slide down. But when I want to click on a link in the sebmenu, it gets disappear. I found a socution for that: I add ".subs:hover" selector to the second. But here it comes another problem, is that if I move my mouse from the bottom to the navbar, the animation begins and the browser detects ".subs" before the animation ends. Finally, the animation turns to the end inmediately, so my submenu 'teleports' instead of slide.

Comment: I don't see this in your example...

Comment: The link works as expected for me.

Comment: Did you copied the code I gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on the issue of why your code wasn't working. I did re-write it to try to get what you were going for using some methods I think are easier to work with.

1. Utilizing `@keyframes` is a great way to build your application with reusable chunks of code.
2. Utilizing translate3d will tap into the GPU of a computer/device for smoother translations.

Please note I did not take the time to add an HTML wrapper that would hide the drop down menus as they fall. This would easily be done by wrapping the entire menu in a `div` and setting the `overflow` to `hidden`.

I apologize I couldn't help you learn more of why you were getting the bug you had.

```css
.sub-menu-parent {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index:-1;
}

.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  animation: 1s slideDown forwards;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -200px, 0px);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:-1;
  }
  99% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:-1;
  }
  100% {
    z-index:0;
  }
}

/* presentational */
body {
  font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

nav a {
  color: #E00;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #F55;
}
nav ul, nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav > ul {
  background: #EEE;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: solid 1px #aaa;
}
nav > ul > li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="sub-menu-parent">
       <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 6</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
       </ul></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your work! I'll check this out in the morning!

Comment: So, I tried the code and I found it good. But when I move the cursor to an other 'li', the submenu disappears inmediately.